# How can I solve a syncing issue between realm and a react native app?

Tags: android, mongodb, react-native, realm

I am new to developing applications with react native using Realm databases, and am having trouble syncing the data though I followed the documentation. The application doesn't throw any errors but crashes whenever I run it, after I call the opening of the realm.
I created the schema from the SDK section in Realm and imported it, as well as copying the AppId.
Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { prescriptionSchema } from './Prescriptions'
import {

    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import Realm from 'realm';

async function start() {

    const appConfig = { id: 'AppId', timeout: 10000 }
    console.log(appConfig)
    const app = new Realm.App(appConfig);
    console.log('created app')
    const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
    console.log(credentials)
    const user = await app.logIn(credentials);
    console.log(user.id)
    try {
        console.log([prescriptionSchema])
        const realm = await Realm.open({
            schema: [prescriptionSchema],
            sync: {
                user: user,
                partitionValue: 'name',
            },
        })

       }

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {

        start();
        return (
            <View>
            
                <TouchableOpacity>

                    <Text>temporary</Text></TouchableOpacity></View>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```

This is the schema:

```
export const prescriptionSchema = {
    name: 'prescription',
    properties: {
        _id: 'objectId?',
        time: 'string?',
        day: 'string[]',
        food: 'string?',
        name: 'string?',
        prescription: 'string?',
    },
    primaryKey: '_id',
};
```

If anyone can find where I went wrong or point me in the correct direction I would be very very grateful!

Comment: I have no experience with Realm, but with a basic look the start function should be in componentDidMount not in render.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that as well and unfortunately it gives me the same problem, but it was definitely worth a shot!